# print bytes which contains NULL

Tags: python, string

I have a bytes string,

```
str = 'string ends with null\x00\x11u\x1ai\t'
```

and I expect that `str` should terminate after the word `null`, because a NULL `\x00` follows immediately, however when I print `str`,

```
>>> print('string ends with null\x00\x11u\x1ai\t')
string ends with nullui
```

`str` doesn't end as I expected, how to make it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> str[:str.find('\0')]
'string ends with null'
```

Python strings are *not* NUL-terminated like C strings. Btw., calling a string `str` is a bad idea as it shadows the built-in type `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate to what @larsmans provided, you can also use [ctypes.c_char_p](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p)

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> st = 'string ends with null\x00\x11u\x1ai\t'
>>> c_char_p(st).value
'string ends with null'
```

And as always unlike `C/C++`, strings in python are not Null Terminated

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate would be to use `split`:

```
>>> str = 'string ends with null\x00\x11u\x1ai\t\x00more text here'
>>> str.split('\x00')[0]
'string ends with null'
>>> str.split('\x00')
['string ends with null', '\x11u\x1ai\t', 'more text here']
```